# doPost Method of AEM SlingServlet can't be called - sling resolver defaulting to GET

Tags: aem, sling

I am working with AEM version 6.2 and I need to create a servlet that connects to a backend system and call a restful service.  This has to done using the doPost method and not the doGet for security reasons.  I have been able to register the Sling based servlet within AEM however, I have not been able to call POST a request to the servlet.  I have registered the using the @SlingServlet annotation using resourceTypes and Paths but still the doPost is not being called only doGet.  I know the default call is to doGet from the server but I have specified the method as POST.

```
package com.dash.dev.servlets.core.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.rmi.ServerException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.sling.SlingServlet;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.DefaultHttpClientConnection;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet;

import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONException;
import org.apache.sling.commons.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository;


@SlingServlet(name="A Servlet2",
resourceTypes = "/apps/DashServletApp/components/structure/page",
paths = "/bin/case/enrol2",
methods = "POST", 
metatype=true)

public class AServletByPath extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7175649210039853979L;
    @Reference
    private SlingRepository repository;

    public void bindRepository(SlingRepository repository){
        this.repository = repository;
    }



protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request,     SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServerException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String sessionID = session.getId();
        System.out.println(sessionID);
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          out.println(sessionID + "POST Method called");
          out.flush();
          out.close();
    }



protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServerException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String sessionID = session.getId();
        System.out.println(sessionID);
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          out.println(sessionID + "POST Method called");
          out.flush();
          out.close();


} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
           finally
           {
               //Important: Close the connect
               httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
           }

    }

}
```

I have read the Sling documnetation and took particular note of:

The request methods supported by the servlet. The property value must either be a single String, an array of Strings or a Vector of Strings. This property is only considered for the registration with sling.servlet.resourceTypes. If this property is missing, the value defaults to GET and HEAD, regardless of which methods are actually implemented/handled by the servlet.

- and when I look at the sling console I see only GET and HEAD registered.  What do I need to do to be able to make the doPost available???

thank you!

Comment: BTW without a doGet I get this error in the log: 30.11.2016 15:57:11.831 *INFO* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1480539431830] GET /bin/case/enrolment2 HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Resource /bin/case/enrolment2 not found.  If I have an empty doGet I get a black page and with the code above I will get the sessionID printed out to the screen

Answer (score 4):

As the naeme suggests the [SlingSafeMethodsServlet](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/servlets/SlingSafeMethodsServlet.html) is supposed to be used only for "Safe" requests, which are `GET`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS` etc. By default this servlet doesn't support `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`.

Quoting the docs

> This base class is intended for applications where data is only read.
>   As such, this servlet by itself does not support the POST, PUT and
>   DELETE methods. Extensions of this class should either overwrite any
>   of the doXXX methods of this class or add support for other read-only
>   methods only.
>
> Applications wishing to support data modification should
>   rather use or extend the SlingAllMethodsServlet which also contains
>   support for the POST, PUT and DELETE methods. This latter class should
>   also be overwritten to add support for HTTP methods modifying data.

You can extend the [SlingAllMethodsServlet](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/servlets/SlingAllMethodsServlet.html) to cater to your `POST` requests.

Comment: No worries. Kindly consider accepting the answer in case it helped